# Типа аськи: выбор языка и технологии

Tags: delphi, flash, java, php, javascript

- Если я напишу типа аськи на java, будет ли программа работать на андройде или в мобильниках кроме компа? (Где будет работать?) Программа нужна для личных нужд.
  Сейчас выбираю язык, на котором буду реализовывать визуальную часть...
- Если делать видео режим типа, как в скайпе, что нужно устанавливать на сервере?
  Что можно установить на php сервере (или vps)?
- Как вот [этот сайт](http://nekto.me/audiochat) сделан, может кто знает? Как сделать общение онлайн?  Как сделать такое же, но только в программе?

Comment: Прежде чем замахиваться на видеочат вы сначала [HelloWorld](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_world_program) напишите...

Comment: пиши на ASM под любой платформой работать будет.

а если серьёзно, то изучай основы, и потом такие вопросы сами по себе отпадут.
да и Java не самый хороший язык для начала обучения.

Comment: "пиши на ASM под любой платформой работать будет" -- ASM'у плевать на тип процессора? Круто!

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/112073/ nekto.me

Answer (score 6):

1. Всё, кроме UI можно перенести с большой Java на Android-ную.
2. Вы можете сделать какой-нибудь peer-to-peer протокол. В противном случае ваш сервер не выдержит нагрузки и всё ляжет. Поэтому лучше видео-поток через сервер не гнать. К тому же, если у вас там обычный PHP-хостинг с ограничением времени выполнения скриптов, то это и вовсе невозможно.
3. На этот вопрос слишком много надо отвечать. Читайте матчасть! Надо придумать протокол передачи и делать либо peer-to-peer, либо гнать через сервер. см. п. 2.

Answer (score 1):

Может стоит начать с: [XMPP](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP)? ;)

Comment: Человеку начинать надо с азов, а уж потом XMPP :)

Comment: @cy6erGn0m, тут изначально хорошая основа, а дальше хоть на джаве, хоть под андроид.. :)